# Are you able to testfor people somewhere on a countdown?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

For a part of my Vanilla world I would like to test for a player on a block.  Then I would like to test for a player standing on another block within a certain duration of time(Like 4 seconds) from when the first testfor was activated.

I'm using 1.9 commands.  Is it possible with the available commands at the time?

Answer (score 3):

I will call "A" the first block you have to stand onto, and "B" the second.

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ A -1 /scoreboard players set @p Timer 80

/scoreboard players remove @a[score_Timer_min=1] Timer 1

/execute @a[score_Timer_min=1] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ B -1 commandyouwanttoexecute
```

Comment: What `"A"` and `"B"` supposed to represent? The block ID or the co-ordinates?

Comment: @aytimothy it means block id

Comment: This would need the 

"/scoreboard objectives add Timer dummy Timer"

to work

Answer (score 1):

1) Arrange redstone in  the same logical order as on this screenshot:

[image: Minecraft Redstone Example]

1.1) All Reapeters DIRECTLY next to a stone block (not the one at the piston) are set to 4 ticks, all the others to 1 tick, the most-down Reapeters are forming a clock.

2) Into the "lower" command block put your first command, into the second place the "after four seconds" command. The delay is set to 4 seconds, but the real delay will be like 4.2-4.4 seconds.